# Visual SVN server project import

Tags: svn, import, project, visualsvn-server

Yesterday I installed **Visual SVN Server**. Created some repository (*with trunk, tags, branch structure*) and tried to import my project into it. But when I looked at repository folder structure it was like this:

[image]

In examples I saw import command is shown without pointing trunk subfolder in the repository URL. Later I tried to make a checkout but there was no **.svn** folder and there was the same folder structure as in my repository.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you have imported your project using URL: https://ALEX-PC/svn/SomeRepository/. If you want to store your project into the "trunk" folder of "SomeRepository", you should import your project using URL: https://ALEX-PC/svn/SomeRepository/trunk/.

As also I noticed that you have BusinessObjectsFramework.suo file in your repository. Files with .suo extension are specific Visual Studio working files and they shouldn't be imported to the repository. I recommend you to use VisualSVN(plug-in) for Visual Studio. It simplify your version control working process with Subversion. VisualSVN has "Add Solution to Subversion" function that adds your solution to the repository. If you will use this function, you need to point right URL as well (as described above).